# Define range for index for lists in for loops

Tags: python, arrays

I'm a complete beginner in *Python*. I was coding the "minimum difference between array elements" problem. The idea was to sort the array and then find the difference between adjacent elements, to find the one with the minimum difference.

However, I wonder how to define the range for the index of the list in for loops so that my index doesn't exceed `size-2`.

```
import sys

a=[34,56,78,32,97,123]
a,size=sorted(a),len(a)
min=sys.maxint

for i,x in enumerate(a):  # Need a range for index i from 0 to size-2
    if(abs(a[i]-a[i+1])<min):  
        min=abs(a[i]-a[i+1])

print min
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use manual indexing, then dont use `enumerate()` and just create a `range()` (or `xrange()` if Python 2.x) of the right size, ie:

```
for i in xrange(len(a) - 2):
   # code here
```

Now you don't have to manually take care of indexes at all - if you want to iterate over `(a[x], a[x+1])`  pairs all you need is `zip()`:

```
for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]):
   if abs(x - y) < min:
       min = abs(x - y)
```

`zip(seq1, seq2)` will build a list of `(seq1[i], seq2[i])` tuples (stopping when the smallest sequence or iterator is exhausted). Using `a[1:]` as the second sequence, we will have a list of `(a[i], a[i+1])` tuples. Then we use tuple unpacking to assign each of the tuple's values to `x` and `y`.

**But** you can also just use the builtin `min(iterable)` function instead:

```
min(abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]))
```

which is the pythonic way to get the smallest value of any sequence or iterable.

Note that with Python 2.x, if your real list is actually way bigger, you'll benefit from using `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`

As as side note, using `min` (actually using any builtin name) as a variable name is possibly not a good idea as it shadows the builtin in the current namespace. If you  get a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` message trying this code you'll know why...

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I wholefully agree but that's the OP's code ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a slice of `a` with the specified start and stop indices to `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(a[:size-1]):
    ...
```

`i` will run from `0` to `size-2`

---

On a side note, comments in Python start with `#` and not `//`

---

You can achieve the same results by using `min` on a generator expression created from the `zip` of `a` and its *advanced slice*:

```
minimum = min(abs(i - j) for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]))
```

Also, be careful to not use the name `min` as this already shadows the builtin `min`. Something you obviously don't want.

Comment: @BusyAnt Not exactly bad.

Comment: `a[:size-1]` to run from 0 to `size-2` if I'm right.

Comment: technically correct but still totally unpythonic. The pythonic way here is to use the builtin `min` function and `zip`

Answer (score 3):

You could just slice `a`. Then `enumerate(a[:-1])` will ignore one element at the end of `a`.

You don't even need to compute `size` anymore!

More so, as you don't use `x` in `i, x`, you don't need `enumerate`. Just use `range` or `xrange`:

```
for i in xrange(len(a)-1):
    ....
```